What happens when you rename a Snapraid parity drive?
Concerning the following /etc/snapraid.conf configuration:
parity /mnt/parity1/snapraid.parity
2-parity /mnt/parity2/snapraid.2-parity
z-parity /mnt/parity3/snapraid.3-parity

What happens when you rename the label of a parity drive, for example renaming 'z-parity' to '3-parity'?
3-parity /mnt/parity3/snapraid.3-parity

According to the manual, you can change parity label names but then after you should run snapraid fix.
Reference: https://www.snapraid.it/manual#7.3
What does snapraid fix do in this scenario? Does it completely rebuild the parity drive in question? I would assume the math would stay the same and it would simply check the drive is intact and has the same uuid. I synced the drives before I edited the config. I then ran snapraid check to see what the output would be:
14871107 errors
0 unrecoverable errors

Running snapraid status says:
No sync is in progress.
No rehash is in progress or needed.
No error detected.

Running snapraid diff says:
1589019 equal
No differences

So I don't know what snapraid fix is going to do. I would like to know a bit more before I run the command. I don't want my data drives to be effected. I only want the 3rd parity drive to be recognized as normal. I would not like it if I had to rebuild everything from backups if running sanpraid fix destroyed data in some way.
Would running snapraid fix -d 3-parity be better? It does not specifically say that in the FAQ so perhaps that would be a mistake. I am asking in case someone with experience has done this before and can explain what is going to happen. I've recovered data drives and parity drives in the past when drives went bad but I usually don't mess with anything when it works.
My exact use case:
I was using 'z-parity' because my CPU did not support SSSE3 and snapraid suggested I use it. I upgraded to a new system and would like to start using the '3-parity' system. Perhaps I should just put it back to 'z-parity' and keep using it as it is. Maybe there is no performance boost to be gained by removing it even with a supported CPU.

I ran snapraid sync and after 80 hours of waiting and wondering if my data would be safe or not by the end, I have the following outcome: 14871107 errors and 14871107 recovered errors. It looks like (from what I can tell so far) the only data modified was parity-3. I still wonder if I could have ran snapraid fix -d 3-parity and the fix would have completed faster. Status and diff report the same data as before.
